# Sql Query Language using subquery

Tags: sql

How do I write a query in sql to update the salary of each instructor to 10,000 times the number of course sections they have taught given the schema below?

Here is the schema of the database:

[image: Attached is the schema of the database]

Comment: Great idea, just do it. But 1 million times would be even better ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query:**

```
UPDATE instructor
SET salary = 10000 *
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM section s
        JOIN teaches t ON s.sec_id = t.sec_id
        JOIN instructor i ON t.id = i.id
        WHERE i.id = instructor.id);
```